# Heap Out of Memory in React Application

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, sass, node-sass

Heap Out of Memory error while starting the application. I have listed my package.json file content which might be needed for proper detailing. Although I set max_old_space_size to 4096, it still provides me the same error. My Pc configuration is 4GB RAM and I5 intel processor. Is it due to my pc configuration or memory leaks in the code. Please elaborate the possible fix for the issue. I face this issue when I use sass in my dev dependencies.

```
    "name": "superadmin-panel",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "license": "MIT",
    "dependencies": {
        "@ant-design/icons": "4.6.2",
        "@auth0/auth0-react": "^1.4.0",
        "@david.kucsai/react-pdf-table": "^0.4.1",
        "@react-pdf/renderer": "^2.1.1",
        "@welldone-software/why-did-you-render": "^6.1.1",
        "antd": "^4.15.0",
        "antd-img-crop": "^3.14.1",
        "apexcharts": "^3.26.0",
        "axios": "^0.21.1",
        "bootstrap-scss": "^4.6.0",
        "chart.js": "^3.0.2",
        "chartist": "^0.11.4",
        "connected-react-router": "^6.9.1",
        "draft-convert": "^2.1.11",
        "draft-js": "^0.11.7",
        "draftjs-to-html": "^0.9.1",
        "emoji-mart": "^3.0.1",
        "feather-icons": "^4.28.0",
        "firebase": "^8.3.3",
        "html-to-draftjs": "^1.5.0",
        "jquery": "^3.6.0",
        "leaflet": "^1.7.1",
        "node-sass": "npm:sass@^1.52.3",
        "react-apexcharts": "^1.3.7",
        "react-bootstrap": "^1.5.2",
        "react-bootstrap-typeahead": "^5.1.4",
        "react-chartist": "^0.14.4",
        "react-ckeditor-component": "^1.1.0",
        "react-clock": "^3.0.0",
        "react-copy-to-clipboard": "^5.0.3",
        "react-countdown": "^2.3.1",
        "react-countup": "^4.3.3",
        "react-data-table-component": "^6.11.7",
        "react-datepicker": "^3.7.0",
        "react-draft-wysiwyg": "^1.14.5",
        "react-dropzone-uploader": "^2.11.0",
        "react-feather": "^2.0.9",
        "react-google-maps": "^9.4.5",
        "react-hook-form": "^6.15.4",
        "react-icons": "^4.2.0",
        "react-image-crop": "^8.6.6",
        "react-image-lightbox": "^5.1.1",
        "react-input-range": "^1.3.0",
        "react-jwt": "^1.1.2",
        "react-moment": "^1.1.1",
        "react-redux": "^7.2.3",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
        "react-router-redux": "^4.0.8",
        "react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
        "react-slick": "^0.28.1",
        "react-slugify": "^2.1.0",
        "react-spinners": "^0.11.0",
        "react-switch-lang": "^1.0.2",
        "react-times": "^3.1.12",
        "react-toastify": "^7.0.3",
        "react-transition-group": "^4.4.1",
        "reactstrap": "^8.9.0",
        "redux": "^4.0.5",
        "redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
        "sweetalert2": "^10.16.0",
        "swr": "^1.2.2",
        "uuid": "^8.3.2"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts  start",
        "build": "react-scripts  build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject",
        "format": "prettier --write './**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,css,md}' --config ./src/.prettierrc"
    },
    "resolutions": {
        "react-dev-utils": "^10.0.0"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": "react-app",
        "plugins": [
            "jsx-a11y"
        ],
        "rules": {
            "no-whitespace-before-property": "off"
        },
        "overrides": [
            {
                "files": [
                    "*-index.js"
                ],
                "rules": {
                    "no-unused-expressions": "off"
                }
            }
        ],
        "reportUnusedDisableDirectives": true,
        "noInlineConfig": true
    },
    "browserslist": {
        "production": [
            ">0.2%",
            "not dead",
            "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
            "last 1 chrome version",
            "last 1 firefox version",
            "last 1 safari version"
        ]
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
        "rc-tween-one": "^3.0.6",
        "react-app-rewired": "^2.1.8",
        "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
        "sass": "^1.52.3",
        "typescript": "^4.2.3"
    },
    "husky": {
        "hooks": {
            "pre-commit": "npx run format",
            "pre-push": "npx run format"
        }
    },
    "engines": {
        "npm": ">=6.0.0",
        "node": ">=14.0.0"
    }
}
```